# How to change jQuery Mobile flipswitch size

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I need a jQuery Mobile flipswitch with custom width & height. I managed to change the size of it by wrapping the flipswitch in a div and applying the following CSS:

```
   #flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch {
       position:absolute;
       width:400px;
       height:100px;
   }

   #flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch-active {
       padding-left:0px;
   }

   #flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch .ui-flipswitch-on,
   #flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch-active .ui-flipswitch-on{
       width:98px;
       height:98px;
   }

   #flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch-active .ui-flipswitch-on {
       padding-top:0px;
       margin-left:300px;
   }
```

However the text is not positioned correctly. Check the jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dinkoivanov/8czs4qzn/

I think I might not be doing the correct thing. Can you advise if that is possible in jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As exemplified [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_select_switch_css) you might need to introduce in CSS

- custom indentations
- custom widths

> because the length of custom labels differs from the length of the
>   standard labels

You can position the text by correcting the indentation in the CSS

```
#flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch .ui-flipswitch-on,
#flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch-active .ui-flipswitch-on{
    width:98px;
    height:98px;
    text-indent: -20em;
}

#flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch-active .ui-flipswitch-on {
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-left:300px;
    text-indent: -18em;
}
```

Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/8czs4qzn/1/

Position the text in the middle (see comment below):

```
#flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
#flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch-active {
    padding-left:0px;
}
#flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch .ui-flipswitch-on, #flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch-active .ui-flipswitch-on {
    width:98px;
    height:98px;
    text-indent: -20em;
}
#flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch-active .ui-flipswitch-on {
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-left:300px;
    text-indent: -18em;
    line-height: inherit;
}

#flipswitchWrapper .ui-flipswitch-off {
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

With vertical alignment of labels: https://jsfiddle.net/8czs4qzn/3/

Comment: You can use line-height for a quick vertical centering of the test: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8czs4qzn/2/

Comment: I updated your fiddle with `line-height:inherit` otherwise one needs to change the CSS two times when changing the height

Comment: Thanks. The "text-indent" was the key to solve the problem, more precisely the ability to specify negative indent.